# Machine learning dataframe dimension concept vs NumPy dimension

Tags: machine-learning, python, r, numpy

From [Machine Learning for Absolute Beginners: A Plain English Introduction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/152095140X):

> Contained in each column is a feature. A feature is also known as variable, a dimension or an attribute - but they all mean the same thing.

From [here](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/tools_numpy.ipynb) (the supplement file for [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1492032646) book):

- In NumPy, each dimension is called an **axis**.
- The number of axes is called the **rank**.

  - For example, the above 3x4 matrix is an array of rank 2 (it is 2-dimensional).
  - The first axis has length 3, the second has length 4.
- An array's list of axis lengths is called the **shape** of the array.

  - For example, the above matrix's shape is `(3, 4)`.
  - The rank is equal to the shape's length.
- The **size** of an array is the total number of elements, which is the product of all axis lengths (eg. 3*4=12)

**Question:** Is the dataframe dimension completely different not related to the NumPy dimension (just same word but describing different concept)?

*I am learning Python and Machine learning but familial with R and R dataframe from statistical perspective*

Comment: I (almost) never hear people refer to a feature as a "dimension"

Comment: @oW_ So you mostly heard (used) in context as is for NumPy? I mean length of the shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataframe case refers to the linear algebraic notion of a dimension.  In the NumPy context, it just means the number of axes or rank.